# Is reference to elements in std::vector safe

Tags: c++11, stl, stdvector

[As I understand it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6438086/iterator-invalidation-rules), as long I do not delete or add items to vector, the items memory location does not change, so I can create a reference to some elements in the vector without worrying they will not be valid.

Is it safe to use refToVec, as long I do not delete/add items to vec??

```
vector<int> vec;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    vec.push_back(i);

vector<reference_wrapper<int>> refToVec;
for (auto &item : vec)
{
    if (item % 2)
        refToVec.push_back(item);
}

//is it safe to use refToVec?
for (auto &item : refToVec)
    item += 100;
```

I am using VS 2013

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's safe. As long as you don't add elements to a vector (beyond what has been `reserve`'d), pointers, references and iterators will stay valid.